# JavaScript Function Problem with Backspace Button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function that is applied to a textbox `onkeyup` so that when a user puts in a date in the format of dd/mm/yyyy it puts in the forward slashes. It also stops the user exceeding ten characters. However, when the user uses the <kbd>backspace</kbd> button, whilst the numbers are deleted, unless you keep down on the button, I can't get the <kbd>backspace</kbd> button to move back beyond the slashes.

Here is my code, and I have highlighted in bold the bit that is not working:

```
function DateInputUpdate(input) {                
    if ( input.value.length == 2 || input.value.length == 5 )
        input.value = input.value + dateSep;

       if (input.value.length > dateFormat.length) {
        input.value = input.value.substring(0, dateFormat.length);

       if (event.keyCode == 8) {
         if (input.value.length == 3 || input.value.length == 6) {
            input.value = input.value.substring(input.value.length, input.value.length - 1);
       }
      }
    }
}
```

Can someone please advise me what I need to do or change? I don't particular wish to delete the slashes, more to ignore them or skip over them that's my ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Because of a missing `}` you are only checking for `keyCode == 8` if the length of the input was greater than the length of `dateFormat`.

Also you are appending a `/` even if the user pressed backspace. This leads to ambiguity.